# Apache DBCP 2: new session created if prepared statement with array is used

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I use Spring Boot, Apache DBCP 2, PostgreSQL 10 and generate the JdbcTemplate via

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(PGProperty.USER.getName(), user);
    props.setProperty(PGProperty.PASSWORD.getName(), password);
    props.setProperty(PGProperty.APPLICATION_NAME.getName(), applicationName);
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + "/db",
            props);
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
    ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory);
    poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
    PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);

    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

I access the DB via

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
...
UUID uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
UUID uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID();
Array array = jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection().createArrayOf("UUID", 
    new Object[] { uuid1, uuid2 });
jdbc.query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ANY (?)", //
    ps -> ps.setArray(1, array), //
    rs -> {
        ...
    });
```

Everytime this select query is called a new session to the DB is created.

If I ommit the prepared statement and call the DB via

```
jdbc.query("SELECT * FROM my_table "
        + "WHERE id IN ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb')",
        rs -> {
            ...
        });
```

everything works fine: no new session to the DB will be created.

How can I use the prepared statement in the right way that no new session will be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection().createArrayOf` is obtaining new connections, and leaking connections as you never close that obtained connection.

If you want to obtain the connection used by `JdbcTemplate`, you need to use [`DataSourceUtils.getConnection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection-javax.sql.DataSource-).

However, you don't need to create that array, `JdbcTemplate` has explicit support for using lists for `IN`, see [Passing in lists of values for IN clause](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-in-clause) in the Spring documentation. Or alternatively, consider the approach using `SqlTypeValue` described in [Handling complex types for stored procedure calls](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-complex-types).